# Binding toggle button to two commands

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a toggle button in my silverlight application as follows:

```
<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Margin="0,30,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ChkToggleButton}" />
```

The toggle currently is changing visual states on toggle and nothing more.
However, I need to bind each of the toggle with a different command. For eg: On button press1, run `command1` and on button press again, run `command2`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Triggers`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42988/Silverlight-Behaviors-and-Triggers-Making-a-Trigge.aspx) for such purposes:

```
<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Margin="0,30,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ChkToggleButton}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FirstCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SomeParameter}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SecondCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding AnotherParameter}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ToggleButton>
```

If you don't have `Interactivity` you can get it by installing [Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) or as a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/).

Comment: I didn't immediately know what xmlns i was mapped to so I looked it up for those that might not know.  It is  System.Windows.Interactivity and is in the Blend SDK.  You can get it here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/

Answer (score 3):

use a single command and also keep track of the toggle state.

Have a viewmodel (preferably, or some codebehind) and let it use these two inputs to decide what actually needs to be done.